# Providing IE11 support in Angular 13

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, frontend, internet-explorer-11

Google has [removed IE11 support](https://blog.angular.io/angular-v13-is-now-available-cce66f7bc296) in Angular 13. In the company that I work for, we have to keep IE11 support for the next few months due to contractual obligations.

As it's unclear what is the extent of removed "IE11 related code" from the framework, we are wondering if it's doable in practice to provide polyfills that would enable us to upgrade to Angular 13 and keep supporting IE11.

Have any of you researched this issue in-depth and successfully provided IE11 support after upgrading to Angular 13?

Comment: Probably there will be an official guide for keeping IE11 support even after Angular v13. My main idea is that you will have to manage all polyfills and IE11 related codes by yourselves, as Angular noted in the official RFC doc, that they will leave the chance to keep up the compatibility with IE11. So in my opinion, there is a solution for this, maybe not fully  clear what is that yet. I will give a look for this now.

Comment: I think this will be very difficult. Even Microsoft will end support for IE in June 2022 and has already moved to the new Edge. I think what you can do is support it in 12 while you migrate to 13, or drop support. Either way, you need to act.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marcin,

The Advocate Developer for the Angular blog gave a brief description about this in the blog for the new version - https://blog.angular.io/angular-v13-is-now-available-cce66f7bc296

> Thanks to everyone who participated in the request for comments
> (RFC). Developers who still need to support IE11 users for existing
> projects can continue to use Angular v12 and it will be supported
> until November 2022.

Since you have to keep the IE11 support only for the next few months, I think you can keep v12 till then. Of course, this is a solution if you do not need a new feature from v13.